# Internal keyboard and trackpad quit working, mac not booting up properly

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, battery, mouse, trackpad

TL;DR I have an early 2015 Macbook Pro (stock features), running Yosemite (not sure of the version). I've tried SMC and PRAM resets, taking the battery out, and external mouse and keyboard with limited success.

A few months ago, the internal keyboard and trackpad would work intermittently, but after a week or so, they quit working altogether. The power button still works. Though, I'm now experiencing issues with the computer's bootup. Sometimes when I boot it up, it shows the Apple logo and then quits. This didn't happen before. And before I get into it, the internal keyboard and trackpad don't work during bootup either. I can't use them to boot into safe mode or reset the PRAM or SMC. I need an external keyboard for that.

I was traveling in Southeast Asia at the time with no Apple store within a few thousand miles, so I didn't go see anyone about it. I read forum after forum, and asked questions. I was told (and convinced) by several people that the problem was a swollen battery. In Malaysia, I took the bottom off of my computer, which seemed to make it a little more stable. It created more room in the computer body, and lent credibility to the swollen battery idea. In Asia, I just couldn't get what I needed to take the battery out and try it. I went to an internet cafe in Indonesia and borrowed a mouse and keyboard. I was hoping to install a driver to use my iPhone as a new wireless mouse and keyboard. My experience was less than stellar. The computer was super jumpy. The mouse and keyboard barely worked. I'm not sure if it was the computer's fault or the cheap equipment at the cafe. Restarting the computer didn't seem to do anything.

Fast forward to London, I was at my mother-in-law's house. She had the security I needed to work on my computer as well as an external mouse and keyboard. They worked great! The computer was not jumpy like it was in Indonesia. I took the battery out (please don't give me flack about how my battery is non-removable, I know what I'm doing). To my surprise, the internal keyboard and trackpad still didn't work.

I'm back in Berlin where I now could go to an Apple store, but I'm also in the best place to work on it myself, and I'd like to take one last stab at it before I pay some extortionate fee to have it fixed. Does anyone have any ideas, that don't have to do with the battery, of why this could happen to a pretty new computer?

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, it's definitely worth you taking it in to an Apple Store. I have known Apple to do repairs and/or replacements even when the item is technically outside their warranty period. Of course, each case is different, and it will depend on the What, When, How and Why of your situation. In a nutshell, it doesn't hurt to ask.

**Secondly**, although it does sound like you know what you're doing, can you confirm you used the correct procedure for resetting the SMC for your particular MacBook? The steps should be:

1. Shut down your computer.
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (power cable) plugged in.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) and the power button.
4. Let go.
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

**Thirdly**, since you've now got access to an external keyboard and mouse, have you tried starting in Safe Mode? If so, what happened? If not, can you try it now and report back?

**Finally**, since you've now got access to an external keyboard, have you tried using Apple Diagnostics? You can do this by:

1. Ensure your MacBook is plugged in to a power source.
2. Do a full shutdown of the computer.
3. Press your power button and immediately press and hold the <kbd>d</kbd> key until you see Apple Diagnostics start.
4. Let the process finish and take note of the results.

Please share your results.

Answer (score 0):

So I read this somewhere in a apple forum and it worked.  I have an 2015 MacBook Pro. My key board was not working after sleep and then it just didn't work anymore. Super annoying.  I was plugging a usb keyboard in and using it with no issues.

I turned off (unchecked) the "animate opening applications" 
You can access this in Dock Preferences

Then I deleted all unused Bluetooth devices and went to advanced options and UNCHECKED the 3 options listed

1 - Open Bluetooth set up assistant at start up if no keyboard is detected

2 - Open Bluetooth setup assistant at start up if no mouse or trackpad detected

3 - Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer.

Since I did this no issues on the wake up problem with key board not working.